# How to remove dynamically generated for id in jquery validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove dynamically generated for id in jquery validation time.
I have a one file upload button and i write a validation rules for upload button.
If i does not choose any image it displayed required message.Now i click a required message it do file upload functionality.That required message have a same id for upload button.it generated dynamically.

How to remove the dynamically generated for id.

This my browse button coding:

```
<input type="file" name="userfile1" id="userfile1" class="span5" ></input>
```

This is my validation rules:

```
$(this).rules("add", {
        required: true,
        messages: {

            required:"<br>Must Select Image To Upload<br>"
        }
    });
```

add is my submit button name.if i click "Must select image to upload" it do file upload functionality because it have same id for browse button.how to i remove it.

kindly give a solution.

Comment: What generates the ids?

Comment: <label class="error" for="userfile1" generated="true">

Comment: for="userfile1" this is same to browse button id.How to remove it in dynamically

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are saying. Can you post your submit button HTML and all the related Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: <label class="error" for="userfile1" generated="true">

Comment: <label class="error" for="userfile1" generated="true">                   How to remove for-="userfile1" in dynamically

Comment: `$("label .error").attr("for") = "someOtherId";`

Comment: is http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8qazf/2/ the problem

Comment: solution: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8qazf/3/ ?

Comment: Thank you so much.I work correct.